# Subtract item quantity and display the remains

Tags: google-sheets, accounting

I'm trying to pull available quantity by sold item, quantity, price in google spreadsheet.
I've been using =`max(sum..)` function and realized it doesn't work that way.

As uploaded image,

1. Identify 'sell quantity, price' and deduct'buy quantity' by price.
       (sell price should be higher than buy price)
2. Display 'available quantity' by 'price range'

Thank you for your time and help!

Sample Image[image]

Comment: Seems like something more easily managed in a script/program and not via cell formulas. `sort` with `sumproduct` could work. Idea being, sort all bought rows and sold rows occurring on or before the current row, and then pass those inputs to a `sumproduct` which handles adding them together.